# const char array multiple initialization c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, char, constants

I have a `const char` array in `Base` class.

```
static const char *_myArray[10];
```

I have created a child `Child1` class's CPP file and can initialize `_myArray[10]` using the below syntax.

```
const char *Base::_myArray[10] = {"red", "green", "blue"};
```

I created another child name `Child2` and I need to intialize this array with `{"pink", "yellow", "brown"}` values.

I tried similarly in `Child2`, however, it couldn't intialize the array using this way. It gives compile error that there is problem with multiple intialization.

I am using this array from my Base classes instance (casting from derived class) and data should be filled up from derived classes (as data may vary from child to child).

What is the right approach to solve this problem?
Your support is highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You know that there won't be two `_myArray`s? It's the same for all instances of all derived classes.

Comment: don't make it static or move your array declaration to the sub-classes.

Comment: what are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: @RichardHodges:
my intention is to use an array from my base (base class own that protected array). however, array data is dynamic and will be determined from my derived classes. The problem arises if there are more than one child classes.

Comment: @mirzapinku will the contents of the array be the same for every object of the same class? I.e. Is it identifying a type, or is it different for each instance of the object?

Comment: Yes.. content is same for every object of the same class. that is why i am trying to create constant char []

Answer (score 1):

static variable can be initialized once. When initializing static member you tell the compiler in which compilation unit this static variable go. You have already initialized the variable in Child1, you can't do it in Child2.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the `static` keyword. It means that all instances of this class share the one array (and the array would even be accessible without any instance if declared public). So you initialize the array with `{"red", "green", "blue"}`, after that, a change is not possible anymore as the array is `const`. Then you try to initialize it again with `{"pink", "yellow", "brown"}` which will lead to the error.

Why does this array have to be static? Remove the static and do the initialization in your initialization list in the constructor.

Here is the correct syntax for this approach:

```
Base::Base() : _myArray{"red", "green", "blue"} 
{
    // Constructor here
}
```

And what I also noted is the issue, that you treat this one dimensional array two dimensional. Each cell of your array can store exactly one character, not a C-String. You could work around that by using two dimensional arrays or by using an array of `std::strings`.

Comment: i have tried to intialize like 
Child1 :: Chiled1 : _myArray({"red", "green", "blue"})
{

}

Child2 :: Chiled2 : _myArray({"Black", "white", "brown"})
{

}
But shows syntext error..

Comment: Edited the answer to contain the neccessary informations

Comment: Base::Base() : _myArray{"red", "green", "blue"} 
{
    // Constructor here
}
this is okay for base.
however, if want to do this from child like
Child::Child() : _myArray{"red", "green", "blue"} 
{
    // Constructor here
}
then error arises.

Comment: Of course that will not work if the array is private. If the array is protected this will also work as its a accessible member for the child. If you would provide the neccessary parts of the class in your question this could be answered the better way.

Comment: OfCourse the array is protected.

Below is the class -

class MyBaseClass {

protected:
 MyBaseClass();

protected:
 enum class PConst{
  TEST_CASE_MAX = 24,
  PATTERN_MAX = 10
 };

 bool _exit;
 char *_myArray[10];
};

Comment: Please edit your question with that code. No one can read it properly in the comments!

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to approach this problem:
One way is to explicitly write static member each time in class:

```
class Base {/*...*/};

class InheritedFirst : public Base
{
    static constexpr const char* _myArray[10] = {"First"};
};

class InheritedSecond : public Base
{
    static constexpr const char* _myArray[10] = {"Second"};
};
```

Another is to derieve from template class with current class as template argument:

```
class Base {/*...*/};

template<typename T>
class GimmeArray
{
    static const char* _myArray[10];
};

class InheritedThird : public Base, public GimmeArray<InheritedThird>
{/*...*/};

class InheritedFourth : public Base, public GimmeArray<InheritedFourth>
{/*...*/};

template<typename T>
const char* GimmeArray<T>::_myArray[10] = {"Not specialized"};
template<>
const char* GimmeArray<InheritedThird>::_myArray[10] = {"Third"};
template<>
const char* GimmeArray<InheritedFourth>::_myArray[10] = {"Fourth"};
```

Comment: IMHO this would be an overkill in his case. He should just remove the static and treat the array as a member...

Comment: I have tried your first approach. It gives below error-
constexpr static data member '_myArray' must have an initializer

FYI: 
Base.h [declared]
static constexpr const char *_myArray[10];

Child1.CPP
static constexpr const char static constexpr const char *Child1::_myArray[3] = {"red", "green", "blue"};

Child2.CPP
static constexpr const char *Child1::_myArray[3] = {"black", "white", "brown"};

What could be wrong with me?

Comment: Do you have c++11 enabled? If no, remove = and beyond, and define arrays outside classes

Comment: yes.. I have C++11 enabled.. 
and I have initialized in the CPP file.

Answer (score 0):

Objective:

Provide an array of words, stored once for each derived class. All instances of the same class shall share the same array of words.

Access to the shared array shall be polymorphic, so that an observer may have access to the array without knowing the exact type of the object.

In which case I would have a non-polymorphic interface function on the base class, which defers to a polymorphic implementation.

The implementation will be defined once per derived class and shall serve up a reference to a static const array of words.

Being static const, c++ will guarantee that it is created on first use. c++11 will guarantee that construction is atomic.

something like this:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using words_array = std::array<const char*, 3>;

struct has_words_base
{
public:
    const words_array& get_words() const
    {
        return get_words_impl();
    }

private:
    virtual const words_array& get_words_impl() const
    {
        static const words_array _ { "grey", "black", "brown" };
        return _;
    }

};

struct blue_words : has_words_base
{
private:
    virtual const words_array& get_words_impl() const override
    {
        static const words_array _ { "blue", "cyan", "indigo" };
        return _;
    }

};

struct red_words : has_words_base
{
private:
    virtual const words_array& get_words_impl() const override
    {
        static const words_array _ { "red", "vermillion", "scarlet" };
        return _;
    }
};


void test(const has_words_base& ob)
{
    auto sep = "";
    for (auto&& w : ob.get_words()) {
        std::cout << sep << w;
        sep = ", ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

}

int main()
{
    test(*std::make_unique<has_words_base>());
    test(*std::make_unique<blue_words>());
    test(*std::make_unique<red_words>());

}
```

expected output:

```
grey, black, brown
blue, cyan, indigo
red, vermillion, scarlet
```